# BigQuery: How to aggregate records in a STRUCT or JSON field?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to aggregate a pair of columns as a dictionary of key,value pairs to construct a STRUCT or a JSON STRING over multiple records.

Currently my implementation leverages the STRING nature of JSON & STRING_AGG to build such a JSON value:

```sql
SELECT
    id, 
    (
        "{" ||
        STRING_AGG(
            '"' || base.key || '":' || CAST(base.val AS STRING),
            ','
        ) || "}"
    )
    AS json_val
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, "a" AS `key`, 100 AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, "b" AS `key`, 200 AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, "c" AS `key`, 300 AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "a" AS `key`, 400 AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "b" AS `key`, 500 AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "c" AS `key`, 600 AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, "a" AS `key`, 700 AS val
) base
GROUP BY 1
```

Which results in the following:

```
id,json_val
1 ,{"a":100,"b":200,"c":300}    
2 ,{"a":400,"b":500,"c":600}    
3 ,{"a":700}
```

Is there a more readable approach? Kind of a STRUCT_AGG(key_field STRING, value_field ) or equivalently signed JSON_DICT_AGG/JSON_STRUCT_AGG?

Comment: I'm surprised Google doesn't implement this on their end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT id, 
  REPLACE(TRANSLATE(FORMAT('%T', ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(key, val))), '[]()', '{}'), '", ', '":') json_val
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, "a" AS `key`, 100 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, "b" AS `key`, 200 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, "c" AS `key`, 300 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "a" AS `key`, 400 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "b" AS `key`, 500 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, "c" AS `key`, 600 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, "a" AS `key`, 700 AS val
) base
GROUP BY id
```

with output

[image]

If you want to wrap up this into UDF - see below example

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ARRAY_TO_JSON(arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  REPLACE(TRANSLATE(FORMAT('%T', arr), '[]()', '{}'), '", ', '":')
);
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(key, val))) json_val
FROM (
. . .
) base
GROUP BY id
```

And btw, you can do exactly same "trick" with your own version - as in below example

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ARRAY_TO_JSON(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT "{" || STRING_AGG('"' || key || '":' || val) || "}"
  FROM UNNEST(arr)
));
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(key, val))) json_val
FROM (
. . . 
) base
GROUP BY id
```

All with same output already presented on the top of the answer

Comment: While this is a pretty genius solution, I think it diminishes the readability. In comparison, a STRING_AGG solution is more approachable. If you can wrap your logic in a UDF that takes an ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, ANY>> then the accepted solution is yours ;)

Comment: Already done! :) N.B: The name of the columns have to be explicitly named "key" and "val" for the function to work. I think it would be more robust if used with a named STRUCT typing: CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ARRAY_TO_JSON_DICT(pairs ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, val STRING>>) AS (( SELECT "{" || STRING_AGG('"' || key || '":' || val) || "}" FROM UNNEST(pairs) AS pair ));

Comment: agree. you can use explicit schema vs. any type